# the sufficient condition for $det A\neq 0$, where $A$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. I was wondering if the following assertion is true:

> if $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n,$ $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=y$, then $\det A \neq 0$

It is well known that the converse is true.

I would be grateful if you give any comment for my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is true as it means that the range of A is the full space and therefore the kernel is reduced to the zero vector (according to rank-nullity theorem). This finally implies that the determinant isn't vanishing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_i=\begin{pmatrix}y_{i,1}\\y_{i,2}\\\vdots\\y_{i,n}\\\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for $i=1,2,\cdots, n$, where $y_{i,i}=1$ and $y_{i,j}=0$ if $i\ne j$

$\exists\; x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax_i=y_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

Here $A\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_2 &\cdots&x_n\end{pmatrix}=I$.

$A$ is non-singular.

Comment: I like your answer. It is simple and clear. Thanks for your answer.